# How to call on a variable which has been defined in a previous function?

Tags: python, function, variables, return, nameerror

My code is as follows...

```
def addition(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

And I then want to be able to use C later on in the program as a variable. For example...

```
d = c * 3
```

However, I get a NameError that 'C' is not defined... But I have returned c, so why can I not use it later on in the code?! So confused. Thanks!

(This is obviously a simpler version of what I want to do but thought I'd keep it simple so I can understand the basics of why I cannot call on this variable outside my function even though I am returning the variable. Thanks)

Comment: how do you call `addition` function ?

Comment: You need to assign the return value of the function to a new variable `c` e.g. `c = addition (a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have returned the *value* of `c` but not the whole variable i.e. the name `c` exists only within the scope it is instantiated.

So, if you want to use the *value returned*, you should re-assign it to a new name. You can do it by re-assigning it to `c` again, but it could be any name you wanted.

```
def addition(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

new_var = addition(1,2) #new_var gets the value 3
c = addition(2,3) #c gets the value 5
```

Take a look at this nice explanation about variables and scopes ([link](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html))

Answer (score 1):

You usually define a function to **use** it later in your code. For that case, use another global variable `c`:

```
def addition(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

c = addition(1, 2)
d = c * 3 # d == 9
```

Functions allow this usage of repeated code, or procedure distinction, so that you can later write in your code

```
m = addition(4, 5)
```

and it will store the required result of the functionality into `m`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define `c` in the function and use it later, you can use global variables.

```
c = 0

def addition(a, b):
global c
c = a + b
return c
```

It's not considered good to use globals, though. You could also call the function in the variable assignment.

```
d = addition(a, b) * 3
```

For this, you need to put real numbers in the place of `a` and `b`. I recommend you use the second option.